# Exporting band data of a large number of points

Tags: export, google-earth-engine, google-fusion-tables, band

I have a question regarding exporting a data from GEE. 
I am new to coding and GEE. What I would like to achieve is export pixel band data of points a have managed to upload using Fusion Table. 
Is is possible for GEE to export band data of those point in form of a table?

My code so far:
 https://code.earthengine.google.com/8a764b5d22a9f7108152fce1acc1fe16

The code:

```
// Load a FeatureCollection from a Fusion Table
var CRuHM_small_data = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1ocXhbAqP_NbA0iE7tivKgKCfTFGseNdibklZj0NX');

// Print and display the FeatureCollection.
Map.addLayer(CRuHM_small_data,{},'CRuHM_small_data');
print(CRuHM_small_data);

//Navigate to area of interest
Map.setCenter(17.3834, -0.8929, 8);

// Select a specific Sentinel-2 image from the archive
var sent2a = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2/20170801T090021_20170801T091620_T33MYV");

// Add RGB composite to map, for water/land
Map.addLayer(sent2a,{bands:['B8','B11','B4'], min:0, max:3000}, "water/land");

However, the next step is more complicated for me. 
I was trying this code, but something is missing:(

//exporting band data to table
//Export.table.toDrive(collection, description, folder, 
//fileNamePrefix, fileFormat, selectors),

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: CRuHM_small_Data,
  description: "CRuHM_small_Data",
  folder: "GEE",
  fileNamePrefix: "Table",
  fileFormat: "CSV",
  selectors: ["ID", "B3", "B2"]
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Coding questions are expected to contain code. While a link to a more involved example might be useful, we need to actual code **in the question**, because links fail over time, and asking volunteers to follow links doesn't result in an increased response rate.

Comment: Thank you for editing my post. How did post the code in separate window?

Comment: Use the `{}` button to indent all code four spaces. SE does the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the sulution.

```
// Print and display the FeatureCollection.
 Map.addLayer(survey_points,{color:'red'},'survey_points');
print(survey_points);

//Navigate to area of interest
Map.setCenter(17.3834, -0.8929, 8);

// Select a specific Sentinel-2 image from the archive
var sent2a = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2/20170801T090021_20170801T091620_T33MYV");


//sampleRegions(collection, properties, scale, projection, tileScale, geometries)

var pixelsID = sent2a.sampleRegions(survey_points, ['ID', 'Depth'], 10);

print(pixelsID)

//Export table toDrive

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: pixelsID,
  description: "pixelsID",
  folder: "GEE",
  fileNamePrefix: "Calibration_Band_Values",
  fileFormat: "CSV",
  selectors: ["ID",'Depth', "B2", "B2",]
  });
```